# Перевод существительного в множественную форму

Tags: php, yii2

Задача следующая, нужно перевести существительное в множественную форму, например:

> товар - товары, статья - статьи, запись - записи, стул - стулья и тд.

Если есть решение для yii2, было бы вообще супер.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Есть решения. Называются messages правда при интернационализации https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-i18n  ..... http://sauron.org.ua/post/1115

Comment: Алексей спасибо за ответ, данное решение уже видел, но оно мне не совсем подходит или я что то не правильно понял. Здесь идет привязка к численному значению. Мне же нужно что бы я отдавал строку в единственном числе 'статья', а получал 'статьи', исходная строка создается динамически, т.е. я не могу подставлять в скрипт модификации (строка, строки, строк и тд). Надеюсь доступно объяснил

Comment: Вот этот должен помочь https://github.com/wapmorgan/Morphos

Comment: Да, это то что нужно, спасибо огромное!!!

Answer (score 0):

В Yii2 это можно сделать с помощью `yii\helpers\Inflector\singularize()`, обратное преобразование `yii\helpers\Inflector\pluralize()`, но придется добавить перевод слов и при необходимости расширить список. Также можно воспользоваться методом `Yii::t()` [см. руководство](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/tutorial-i18n#mnozestvennoe-cislo).

Comment: Спасибо, изучил руководство, тоже подходящий вариант